# ¿Cómo se trabaja con el número ⅇ (número de Euler) en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber cómo trabajar con el número ⅇ en JavaScript y cómo escribirlo para que lo tome como tal.

Comment: BAJO que escenario? Que intentas hacer? Coloca una descripción

Comment: Intenta poner un ejemplo, ¿Que has intentado ahora? ¿Cuando lo haces que tipo de problemas tienes? Da más información sobre tu problema para que puedan ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios. Estamos haciendo una calculadora simple desde TDD y se me había ocurrido que si alguien quería meter el número e, que detectase el string y lo convirtiese al número e y pudiese operar

Comment: Tenéis toda la razón del mundo, no había especificado el escenario. Gracias :):):) Que tengáis buen día :):):)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El número *ⅇ* (o número de Euler) está almacenado en [`Math.E`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/E). No necesitas (ni se recomienda) teclearlo o calcularlo tú mismo.

Puedes usarlo como tal en operaciones matemáticas de la siguiente manera:

```js
 console.log('Valor de ⅇ: ', Math.E);
 console.log('ⅇ · 5: ', Math.E * 5);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! me has alegrado la mañana :)